# Intersection of two three dimensional hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two hyperplanes of dimension 3. The intersection is a hyperplane of dimension 2.

Given
`ax = b` and
`cx = d` as the hyperplanes of degree 3.

How can i get an equation for the intersection?